# Change the language of the system in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: language-support, mate

I installed Ubuntu Mate in an old netbook. At first I chose the system to be in a language different than English, but once the installation was complete I changed my mind. So through the Language Support I changed the language to English and then pressed Apply System-Wide. But after restarting, although the names of the panel items were in English the date and the folders inside the home directory were not. Why didn't they change? Also how can I change them? I can do it manually and it is not much effort but I wonder why they didn't change and if there is an automatic way.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually two questions.

To change the folder names, open a terminal window and run this command:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

If you want the dates etc. in English, and not only the display language, you can open *Language Support* again and [select an English option in the Regional Formats tab](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html).